# Gain access to field in Generic class?

Tags: c#, generics

I have 4/5 tables with a same named column in each table. To give an example Category, SubCategory and Products table all have a column called `DateCreated`.

I currently have the below structure in my class

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly DbContext _context = null;
    private readonly DbSet<T> _entities;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _entities = _context.Set<T>();
    }

    public T Add(T entity)
    {
        return _entities.Add(entity);
    }
}
```

Using the above structure i can create a Category Class (or any other) which references the `IRepository` interface and gives me these methods for all CRUD operations and pass in that type.

Is there a way using the above generic approach, i could set and get the `DateCreated` field as i need to carry some functionality on this for all tables but referring to the table itself i.e. Category or Sub Category etc?

Example i have something similar being used in a non generic class Customer class

```
 public void AmendDateConflict(Customer c)
    {
        if (c != null)
        {
            nc = Get(c.Id);

            if(c.DateCreated)
            {
            // Rest of code removed 
        }
    }
```

but as you can see `c` has access to the field `DateCreated` but not sure if there is a way to introduce the same concept for certain classes? Or just keep it simple and copy and paste the same code into other classes and change the Type?

Comment: You should create a base class with the common properties and your type constraint of the repository should be `where T : MyBaseClass`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a base class for your entities with common properties like DateCreated. Than you can override SaveChanges method to automatically fill those properties with desired values when saving or updating an entity.

```
public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        foreach (EntityEntry<BaseEntity> entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<BaseEntity>())
        {
            switch (entry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    entry.Entity.CreatedBy = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(_currentUserService.UserId) ? Guid.Parse(_currentUserService.UserId) : null;
                    entry.Entity.Created = DateTime.Now;
                    entry.Entity.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                    break;

                case EntityState.Modified:
                    entry.Entity.LastModifiedBy = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(_currentUserService.UserId) ? Guid.Parse(_currentUserService.UserId) : null;
                    entry.Entity.LastModified = DateTime.Now;
                    break;
            }

            return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that this override should be in your DbContext class :)

Comment: A little lost here so i have this in the Category class `public class CategoryRepository : GenericRepository<Category>, ICategoryRepository` do i need to create another class with a property called `DateCreated`?

Comment: basically yes, if you have common properties like DateCreated in your entities (like Category) you could create a class named BaseEntity and inherit it from your entites (like Categoy) (public class Category : BaseEntity) and after you can totally use above code.